# Mysql - Concatenating "Load Data Infile" onto existing Mysql column data

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, concatenation

I'm using the below code to update fields in Mysql through a CSV import which works fine.

```
$sql = "
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE items 
CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(PROD_NO,SUP_NO,NEW_TAGS);

$result = mysqli_query($db2,$insertsql);
```

Now I'm trying to concatenate the values in the third column of the CSV (NEW_TAGS) onto the end of the data which already exists in Mysql (OLD_TAGS column).

I've found examples concatenating a hard string onto imported data, but can't find a way of concatenating the CSV data to whats already in Mysql.

I think it should be something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
$sql = "
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE items 
CHARACTER SET utf8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(PROD_NO,SUP_NO,@NEW_TAGS)
SET OLD_TAGS = CONCAT_WS(',', `OLD_TAGS`,@NEW_TAGS)";

$result = mysqli_query($db2,$insertsql);
```

Example SQL Table:
PROD_NO | SUP_NO | ITEM_NAME | OLD_TAGS
1000 | APPLE | IPHONE | keyword_1,keyword_2
1001 | APPLE | IPOD | keyword_1
1002 | APPLE | IPAD | keyword_1,keyword_2

Example CSV File:
1000 | APPLE | IPHONE | keyword_3,keyword_4
1001 | APPLE | IPOD | keyword_2
1002 | APPLE | IPAD | keyword_3,keyword_4
1007 | ANDROID | PHONE | keyword_1

I have an index on PROD_NO,SUP_NO to make the unique record. When I import the CSV I'd like the old records to be updated to add the new tags, or a new record created which copies the entire old row and concatenates the new data onto the end of the column.

Expected Mysql Table after Load Date Infile:
1000 | APPLE | IPHONE | keyword_1,keyword_2,keyword_3,keyword_4,
1001 | APPLE | IPOD | keyword_1,keyword_2
1002 | APPLE | IPAD | keyword_1,keyword_2,keyword_3,keyword_4,
1007 | ANDROID | PHONE | keyword_1

If this is possible I'd appreciate an example of how it can be achieved. Thanks :)

Comment: An insert represents a completely _new_ record; there is no pre-existing data in any column.  Can you show sample data which would help to explain your question?  You might be looking for an update here, not an insert.

Comment: Thanks, Ive updated with more information and some data :)

Comment: Don't do this.  Stop storing CSV data in your table and instead get each product/brand onto a separate row.  This would completely avoid your current problem while also leaving you with a better table structure.

Comment: 'REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html - if you want to update an existing table then replace is not for you you could insert to a temporary table and update from that,